# Not able to delete pdf created by iText

Tags: java, file-io, itext

I've tried `file.delete()`, `file.deleteIfExits()` and even `file.deleteOnExit()` but nothing seems to work.

Is there any other method to delete a `pdf` that has been created in same process by `iText`?

```
File existing = new File(RESULT);
        existing.deleteOnExit();
```

RESULT is the path to filw which I want to delete.

Comment: Post the file creation code. Are you certain that file.delete() didn't work?

Comment: Have you properly closed all relevant objects?

Comment: @mkl nopes I'm newbie in java... can you plz tell me how to close all objects?

Comment: I meant only those objects that might hold a handle on that file. In thecontext of iText that might be a PdfWriter, PdfStamper, PdfCopy, PdfReader...

Comment: yea i've closed document and pdfwriter too

Comment: In that case iText dies not keep the file from being deleted.

Comment: Two possibilities: 1. The file is still in use or 2. You don't have the rights to delete the file.